# How works a JPA Embeddables class?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts about how works the **Embeddables** JPA class.

So I have this example:

1) A **Customer** entity class that map the **T_CUSTOMER** DB table

```
@Entity
@Table(name= “T_CUSTOMER”)
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column (name=“cust_id”)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride
    (name="postcode", column=@Column(name="ZIP"))
    private Address office;
    …
    …
    …
}
```

2) An **Address** entity class that simply represent an address (and that not map any DB table):

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String suburb;
    private String city;
    private String postcode;
    private String country;
}
```

As you can see in the **Customer** entity class there is this field:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverride
(name="postcode", column=@Column(name="ZIP"))
private Address office;
```

What exactly are the rules and the meaning of the **@Embedded** and **@AttributeOverride** annotations?

I think that this works in the following way:

1) Some column of the **T_CUSTOMER** DB table are mapped not directly into the **Customer** entity class but are mapped and stored into the field of the **Address** class that is a field of the the **Customer** class.

2) The table column named **ZIP** is mapped with the **postcode** property of the **Address** class.

Is it right or am I missing something?

Tnx